# Cannot resolve a maven plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am new to spring-mvc. I have cloned a github project and got problem with open project. That is `Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.3.1`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGJFV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN7TV.png)

**My porm.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>LMS</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <name>LMS Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--    Test-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--    Servlet-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--    spring mvc-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--    MySQL Connector-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--    spring jdbc dependency-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>LMS</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I reloaded the maven project and tried the following method,

- Click File  Settings.
- Build, Run, Deploy Expand  Build Tools  Maven.
- Check Use the plugin registry.
- Click OK or Apply.

  For IntelliJ 14.0.1, open Preferences---not Settings--- to find the plugin registry option:
- Click File  Preferences.
- Regardless of version, invalidate caches:
- 
- Click File  Invalidate Caches / Restart.
- Click Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: First you should check your build on plain command line and define also all other plugins as well... because a lot of them are very old which you are using (because you haven't defined them)...

Comment: Can you build. the project from the command line by Maven: `mvn clean compile`?

Answer (score -2):

Apache Maven WAR Plugin » 3.3.1

There is a new version for this artifact. Try Changing the version to **3.3.2**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Based on which information do you conclude having vulnerbilities?? https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin/3.3.1/overview That plugins has simply being not downloaded and the cache in IDEA might not being update...